# Short story with a mechanical fly

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

Trying to identify a short story from some long-forgotten collection with multiple authors.  All I really remember is a man attempting to swat a fly that landed on him...when a blue flame shoots out of it and it gets away.

Comment: You're going to have to give us more than that... When did you read it? When do you think it was written? Anything else you can think of?

Comment: I belonged to the Science Fiction Book Club around the 1978 to 1982 area...so written a while back.  I seem to remember the author having a Spanish-sounding name.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

["The Fly"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55994) by [Arthur Porges](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/porges_arthur):

> Excited, he reached forward again, but as his plucking fingers approached, the fly rose smoothly in a vertical ascent, lifting a pyramid of taut strands and tearing a gap in the web as easily as a flipped stone. The man was alert, however. His cupped hand, nervously swift, snapped over the insect, and he gave a satisfied grunt.
>
> But the captive buzzed in his grasp with a furious vitality that appalled him, and he yelped as a searing, slashing pain scalded the sensitive palm. Involuntarily he relaxed his grip. There was a streak of electric blue as his prize soared, glinting in the sun. For an instant he saw that odd glowworm tail light, a dazzling spark against the darker sky, then nothing.

You can listen to the [*Mind Webs*](http://www.otrplotspot.com/mindwebs.html) reading of this story at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/MindWebs_201410/The+Snake-The+Fly.mp3).

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!  I would never have found this.  At the time I read it I remember thinking hey this is pretty good...I should look for more stuff by this guy.  Now I can :)

Comment: Other popular stories by Arthur Porges include ["The Ruum"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74067) and ["The Devil and Simon Flagg"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56755).